# How to raise mouse and keyboards events in JS

Tags: javascript, mouse, keyboard-events

Is there a way to send mouse events and keyboard events in JavaScript?
Does all browsers support this need?

-Datte

Answer (score 1):

Yes, browsers support this.
Its not necessarily an easy thing to work with though.

Have a read through:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp

And look up some tutorials in google. There are plenty around!

Answer (score 0):

All browsers do support event models, but Internet Explorer's events work completely differently from the standards implemented by Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc.

If you're going to be building an application that's especially event-intensive, I'd recommend picking up a Javascript framework like JQuery, which solves all the browser incompatibilities for you.

http://docs.jquery.com/Events